# Empty page with pdflatex generated documents while printing

Tags: pdf, pdftex, printing

I am having a HP Color Laserjet 2550Ln. Every time when I am printing a PDF file generated by pdflatex, the printer throws out an additional empty page at the end.

I don't think it's a printer problem, because other PDF files from OpenOffice or the Cups PDF printer don't have that behavior.

What can it be?

Comment: Have you checked with a PDF viewer how many pages the file claims to consist?

Comment: If there *is* an extra (blank) page, perhaps an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) might shed light on way this exists. Otherwise it is hard, if not impossible, to assess what might be the problem.

Comment: Actually I just printed another PDF document from kpdf, generated by CUPS. The extra blank page also happened. Thus, I did some research. No extra blank page with Adobe Reader, Envince or Okular. No extra blank page with kpdf and PS files. That extra page occurs with kpdf and PDF files (not all). Doesn't seem to be an ((pdf)la)tex problem as I was expecting. Probably I will just deinstall kpdf (and use Okular) and the problem is solved.

Comment: Do your documents have an even or odd page total? Is your printer trying to emulate two-sided printing but can print only one-sided?

Comment: Without an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), I consider this problem to be off-topic, since it may be PDF viewer dependent. I was going to suggest "too localized" but there has been no mention of [`xpdf`](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf), the viewer [`kpdf`](http://kpdf.kde.org/) is based on, nor [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) or others. So it may not be that localized. Regardless, an MWE would clear this up.

Comment: Perhaps the page size is wrong. Do some of the printer shrink the page to fit?